# MapView Not Showing Location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm currently developing an iOS app, and one of its functions include locating places of interest for nightlife. However, when my MapView loads, current user location is not displayed, even though location access has been granted.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class BarMapVC: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var searchBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var doneBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var locationBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var barMapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
let regionRadius: Double = 1000

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.isHidden = true
    barMapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self
    configureLocationServices()
    centerMapOnUserLocation()
}

@IBAction func searchBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    searchBar.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func doneBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

@IBAction func locationBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways || authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        centerMapOnUserLocation()
    }
}
}

extension BarMapVC: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func centerMapOnUserLocation() {
        guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        barMapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
}

extension BarMapVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func configureLocationServices() {
        if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else {
            return
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        centerMapOnUserLocation()
    }

}
```

I'm using CLLocation Manager, complying to mapViewDelegate, as well as have all needed outlets. Anything I' m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this on your map view:

```
barMapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

Comment: That definitely worked! I can see User Location now. However, I'm pretty sure I programmatically designed the map to zoom in to its defined coordinateRegion upon loading, but  that isn't occurring either. What do you suggest?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your location is nil when you try to access it and therefore exits the function before you can set a region.